# Laravel - chosing date to see posts from that date with daterangepicker

Tags: laravel, date, range, picker

So I have this project and I almost finished it. I got an answer from my previous question for laravel carbon date and it's working great! It shows me all posts made today because of `$from=$request->has('from')?$request->query('from'):Carbon::now()->subDays(1);
        $to=$request->has('to')?$request->query('to'):Carbon::now()->endOfDay();` and all I need know is daterangepicker in frontend to choose any date I want, and when I choose that date I would see all posts made that day. Please help!

Here is my HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
   /*

public function index(Request $request){

        // set default value for from is yesterday (you can set as per your requirement)
        // set default value for to is today

        $from=$request->has('from')?$request->query('from'):Carbon::now()->subDays(1);
        $to=$request->has('to')?$request->query('to'):Carbon::now()->endOfDay();


       $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                       ->whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to])
                       ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                       ->paginate(30); 

                return view('home')->with(['from'=>$from,'to'=>$to,'posts'=>$posts]);

        }
}
```

Here is my home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.theme')

@section('content')
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="mainl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columna">



                <h1>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h1>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="columns">
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" id="logout"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    {{ __('LOGOUT') }}
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    @csrf
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        </br></br></br>

        @if(count($posts)> 0)
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BR.KESICE</th>
                    <th>IME I PREZIME</th>
                    <th>BR.TELEFONA</th>
                    <th>POSAO</th>
                    <th>CIJENA</th>
                    <th>PLACANJE</th>
                    <th>POPUST</th>
                    <th>DATUM PREUZ.</th>
                    <th>DATUM IZDAV.</th>
                    <th>SMJENA</th>
                    <th>RADNIK</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                    <th>IZMIJENI</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$post->br_kesice}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->ime}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->br_telefona}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->posao}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->cijena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->placanje}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->popust}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->datum_preuz}}</td>
                    @if($post->status == 1)
                        <td>/</td>
                    @else
                        <td>{{$post->datum_izdav}}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{$post->smjena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->radnik}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($post->status == 0)
                        <span class="label label-primary" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 1)
                        <span class="label label-success" id="statusaktivan">Aktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 2)
                        <span class="label label-danger" id="statusdeaktivan">Rejected</span>
                        @else
                        <span class="label label-info" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    @if($post->status == 3)

                    @else
                    <td><a href="posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    @endif

                </tr>

                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to])->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>GOTOVINA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->where('placanje', 'Gotovina')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>VIRMAN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->where('placanje', 'Virman')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        {{ $posts->links() }}
        @else
            <p>Trenutno nema unosa.</p>
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

Any solutions to code daterangepicker in frontend so I can choose any date I want to see posts from that date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include datetimepicker in your application
make two inputs: one for from input  and the another one for to input 
and make filter button when clicked ,send the two value
in your controller
format the dates

```
$from=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->from));
$to=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->to))
  $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                       ->whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to])
                       ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                       ->paginate(30);
```

Comment: So this code I should add in PostsController ? And how can I make filter button for that ?

Comment: if you will make it in ajax take the values to data when you clicked button

$('.btn-filter').click(function(e){
var from=$('.from').val();
var to =$('.to').val();
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
data:{from:from,to:to},
url:url,
type:post
})
})

Comment: If this help you accept the answer to help others,thanks!